# How to join multiple txt by adding parts of the file name and then save csv?

Tags: r, filenames, txt, relational

I need to open multiple txt (all have the same number of variables and variables names, see picture[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oz2n.jpg)]); to each, add multiple columns with specific parts of their file name; then save a CSV resulting from merging all txts, with the added columns corresponding to each txt unique file name.

The file name looks like:

```
NVR_ch2_main_20220505140000_20220505150000
```

and I need three columns:

```
Month (05, the first of the two after 2022),  
Day (05) and  
hour (14).
```

Example of one of the txt sources of datawould

```
dput(head('NVR_ch2_main_20220505132105_20220505140000.txt'))
# A tibble: 41 x 8 
Selection View Channel Begin Time (s) End Time (s) Low Freq (Hz) High Freq (Hz)
type <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl> 
1 1 Waveform 1 1 790. 792. 0 4000 NA 
# ... with 37 more rows
```

I managed the process with the whole file name for one file:

```
read_tsv('NVR_ch2_main_20220505132105_20220505140000.txt') %>%
mutate(filename = 'NVR_ch2_main_20220505132105_20220505140000.txt') %>% 
select(filename, everything ()) %>% 
write_csv('C:/Users/marta/Documents/R/Crete/NVR_ch2_main_20220505132105_20220505140000.csv')
```

Comment: Welcome, Marta. Thanks for supplying code. You wrote there are multiple files that are being read. It'd be nice to have an example of the source of the columns you want to add. You can use `dput(head(sourceofcolumns))` to give examples of data. Are you creating a new object for each file you read? Will the CSV that you write out have the same name as the TSV that read in or is the name changed, beyond going from TSV to CSV? Do the TSVs all have the same format for the name, e.g. ---_--#_----_###############_###############, where "-" = a letter and "#" = a number?

Comment: Well, it's not an answer. It's a comment that is trying to get some clarification for what you want to do. If you can supply the additional information I ask for with that comment, it will be easier to help you. I see the example of the txt source. I'm wondering what the columns are that you are adding to the text. Are the columns coming from some other object or are they part of the files that you are reading in from the file?

Comment: By now, I am creating a new object, but all txt should be merged into one at the end. The name of the resulting CSV doesn't truly matter, as long as it is the results of all txt with the added columns for the file names parts

Comment: For each txt, the new coloumn should come from the file name of that same txt

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

list_of_files <- list.files("C:/Users/marta/Documents/R/Crete", pattern="tsv", full.names=T)

fun1 <- function(x) {
    df1 <- read_tsv(x, comment = "#") 
    newname <- gsub("tsv", "csv", x)
    df1$month <- rep(str_sub(x, 18, 19), nrow(df1))
    df1$day <- rep(str_sub(x, 20, 21), nrow(df1))
    df1$hour = rep(str_sub(x, 22, 23), nrow(df1))
    write.csv(df1, newname)
    }
    
lapply(list_of_files, fun1)
```

You may have to adjust the numbers that are in the `str_sub()` calls so that you get the right position from the file names.

Note the the columns will be probably be characters. If you need numbers for `month`, `day`, and `hour`, you should change `str_sub()` to `as.numeric(str_sub())`.

Comment: I think your `day` is missing a `str_` before `sub`.

Comment: thanks a lot! Unfortunately, I get this error John
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :

Comment: Marta, I made a small edit to my code. It seems the error comes from reading in the file with `read_tsv`, so I tweaked that a little bit.

Comment: John, thanks for your patience. Now Error in is.factor(x) : object 'x' not found

Comment: The problem could also be the `list_of_files`. I made some assumptions about the files and the directory from which you're importing. The `list.files(...)` as I wrote it includes all of the TSV in the directory. If there are TSV in that directory that are very different in some way from the TSV that you want to use, they may require additional attributes to `read_TSV()`.

Comment: The new error should have been obvious to me. Sorry. I made another edit. If that doesn't work, I suggest trying AndS.'s answer. :)

Comment: John, list_of_files works well, I checked it, thanks for your help so far (still can't make it to work tho)

Comment: Marta, I'm sorry. I wrote a couple of bad lines that I should have realized before submitting. If this last edit doesn't do it for you, I'm out of ideas.  Feel free to try the other answer from AndS. if this last edit doesn't work for you. :)

Comment: OMG. That last error is a complete mistake on my part. VERY sorry about that. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I can't promise it will work since I don't have your data, but this should find all files with the common prefix, extract the month day and hour from the file name, and then read all the data in as one combined file:

```r
library(tidyverse)

tibble(file = list.files(pattern = "NVR.*\\.txt")) |>
  extract(file, 
          into = c("month", "day", "hour"), 
          regex = ".*\\w_\\d{4}(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})\\d{4}_", 
          remove = FALSE, 
          convert = TRUE) |>
  mutate(data = map(file, read_tsv)) |>
  unnest(data)
```